# One of the paragraph is replaced by a function's output

Tags: javascript, html

In the code given below the paragraph is erased as soon as we click on the button. Why?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function func_1()
        {
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>First</h1>
    <button onclick="func_1()">Click here </button>

    <p id="show"> Second</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “erased”?

Comment: You mean `Second` being replaced with `Hello World`?

Comment: Your title doesn't match your description. Also, your title talks about a function's output, but your only function has no output. Please clarify your question.

Comment: yes the word "Second" is being replaced by the the word "Hello World".

Comment: That's exactly what your code says to do. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: button is submit, submit buttons submit. My guess is you have a form in your real code `<button type="button" ...>`

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML replace the content of the selected div by the content you give to it. So in your case "Second" is deleted and "Hello world" is added

Answer (score 1):

Not happening for me here

https://codepen.io/shivani137/pen/YLBoJZ

It's working as expected. You sure you don't have any extra code?

below code works fine

```
 document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

Comment: The word "Second" is being replaced by the the word "Hello World". How can I avoid that from happening?

Comment: @NIMITAGRAWAL: By not doing that in your code. What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want the text "Hello World" to be appended, rather than to replace the original text. This version does that.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function func_1()
        {
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML += ". Hello World";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>First</h1>
    <button onclick="func_1()">Click here </button>

    <p id="show"> Second</p>
</body>
</html>
```